# Is it possible to put multidimensional array inside a function?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I wanted to do a function that looks like this function foo($array[], int a, int, b, int c, int d) but it does not work, so i am wondering if it is possible? is it?

Comment: What's your goal exactly?

Comment: Just pass it as normal variable: `function($IDontKnowHowManyDimensions){}`

Comment: Its only a 2d array, it says that unexpected '[' or expecting ')' my code looks like this function foo($x[][], $a, $b, $i, $j)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not C. You don't have to type your variables. Just use:

```
function foo($array, $a, $b, $c, $d) {

}
```

Comment: so u do have to declare it manually then?

Comment: PHP is a scripting language, not a compiled language. Variables are not statically typed. The type of a variable is determined at run-time. In php, you can put an int in a variable that previously contained an array, then overwrite it with a string. If you say that $array is a multi-dimensional array, you write your code assuming that variable is a multi-dimensional array. You can use [`is_array(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to cut the function short if it isn't an array if you wish.